# How to consume the Stack Exchange API in Angular

Tags: angular, stackexchange-api, stackexchange

I have  call below API to get list of answers in angular 6 but I'm getting response null.

API:  https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow

Do I need to pass any header param ?

Does anyone have any idea on how to call the stack-exchange API in angular 6 ? 
Please help me if you know.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the url that i used `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default`

[image]

You can apply these filters via **query params**

I have also created a [stackblitz](https://angular-rhvobt.stackblitz.io) where you can see the response in the console

Comment: Hi,

I have added  my code on below snipped but it not working can you Please help me on same.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9fzet2

Comment: @MitulPatel the URL you used was the docs site. its not the api. Also understand angular. You need to import `httpclient` from your module

Comment: I made changes as you suggested  and I got the desire result. 
Thank you so much HariHaran

Comment: I'm using below link api but it's not working
Please let me know if i'm wrong then give me API links


https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196869/discussion-between-mitul-patel-and-hariharan).